# Find out Key of c# Dictionary when Any() returns true

Tags: c#, dictionary

From the below code I always come to know whether any of the DatFiles is not in sync or not. But how to get which one?

```
bool isNotinSync = DatFileListDictioanry.Any(t => IsThisDatFileNotInSync(t.Key)) // I want a key or Pair here!
```

I know this can be achieved using a simple for loop and checking all the values of the pairs. But is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should help:

If you just need the first /default entry

```
DatFileListDictioanry.FirstOrDefault(t => IsThisDatFileNotInSync(t.Key))
```

If you need the complete list then:

```
DatFileListDictioanry.Where(t => IsThisDatFileNotInSync(t.Key))
```

Comment: DatFileListDictioanry.Where(t => IsThisDatFileNotInSync(t.Key)).Select(keyValue => keyValue.Key).ToList();

This works... Thanks Mrinal! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DatFileListDictioanry.Where(t => IsThisDatFileNotInSync(t.Key)).FirstOrDefault()
```